# MATLAB - Polynomial interpolation with condition in derivates

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a set of values (they represent an angle variation in radiants) and I started to create a polynomial that interpolates all the values.

```
time = 10;
n = 10*time;
t = linspace(0,time,n);
%Th1 is the array of angles 
p1 = polyfit(t,Th1,5); %fifth-grade polynomial
```

Then I wanted to have a polynomial with boundary condition: in t = 0 (first value) and t = time (last value) both first and second derivate have to be equal to zero. The angle is varying from Th1_start to Th1_end. I solved this problem as a linear system

```
t_start = 0;
t_end = time;
syms t;
Mat = [1 t t^2 t^3 t^4 t^5; 0 1 2*t 3*(t^2) 4*(t^3) 5*(t^4); 0 0 2 6*t 12*(t^2) 20*(t^3)];
%Mat is a matrix with 3 rows. Given in the first row a generic fifth-grade polynomial 
%(an angle with respect to the time t) the second row is the first derivate 
%and the third row is the second derivate of the polynomial
%initialize the array to store coefficients
P_theta = zeros(1,6);
%first three rows when t = 0
t = t_start;
A = subs(Mat);
%other rows evaluated when t = time
t = t_end;
B = subs(Mat);
%creating the matrix C and the array V of bounds for the system. 
C = vertcat(A,B);
V = [th_start(i) 0 0 th_end(i) 0 0]';
XX = linsolve(C,V);
P_theta(1,:) = XX;
```

The system has 6 dimension since 6 bounds are given: 2 points (first and last) and 4 condition about derivates in these points. 6 coefficient are found.

Now the question: I have many points (like first case) and I want to add the 4 optional condition about derivates in the first and last point (like in the second case). *Is there a fast way in Matlab to find the correct polynomial without writing a system of (N+4)th order?*

A small example. With 10 points I obtain

```
th1 = [0.0840 0.1480 0.2127 0.2792 0.3478 0.4188 0.4926 0.5693 0.6496 0.7338]
```

With `polyfit` I wouold obtain some coefficient that does satisfy the conditions ( Naming Th1(t) the ideal polynomial )  (pseudocode)

```
Th1(t = 0) = th(1)
Th1(t = time) = th(10)
```

And implicitly the polynomials satisfy all other 8 conditions like (if the degree of the polynomials is more than / equal to ten). These type of conditions are satisfied by the system but are not satisfied by interpolation.

```
Th1(t(i)) = th1(i)
```

but does not satisfy these 4 conditions (pseudocode)

```
d(Th1(t = 0))/dt = 0 %first derivate evaluated in t = 0
d(Th1(t = time))/dt = 0 %first derivate evaluated in t = 0
d2(Th1(t = 0))/dt = 0 % second derivate evaluated in t = time
d2(Th1(t = time))/dt = 0 %first derivate evaluated in t = 0
```

There are 14 conditions. I want to avoid to write a linear system with 14 equations. I dont' want to discard ore choose some points in order to have less equations. *How to add these last 4 conditions to a method like polyfit?*

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I am confused: didn't you just say that you got all points you wanted, by solving the linear system? Do you want to avoid having to solve the linear system (because it's time-consuming etc.)? Do you want to filter out some irrelevant solutions? It would help a lot if you show a small sample of the inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: I have many points (100+). Instead of these points I want to retrieva a polynomial (its coefficient) that interpolates these points the best that is possible. With 100 points I will have to write "by hands" 104 equations for the system (I don't know how to do it fast). I will provide a small sample

Comment: I really hope you're not trying to fit a [polynomial of degree 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) to some data....

Comment: @Dev-iL That is quite the final purpose (but I am not looking for "exact fitting" in every point (nodes): I want to avoid it keeping a low degree of the polynomial, if it possible) Interpolation would be less precise but acceptable. Of course if I use the "system" method I would obtain a N+4 degree: with 100 points it is not acceptable.

Comment: I think you'd be better off fitting a smoothing spline automatically (basically it's a piecewise cubic polynomial) instead of messing with this manually. if you ABSOLUTELY MUST fit a crazily-high-degree polynomial (though, again, **I strongly advise against it**), you could use the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). If you fit a spline through MATLAB, you can get the coefficients of all pieces from the resulting `struct`.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thank you very much. Do you know some good pages of examples that you can link here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131728/discussion-between-dev-il-and-marcoresk).